# UpdatePanel does not work when AjaxControlToolkit lib is included

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I work on a simple ASP Webform project (asp framework 4.0), and use VS 2010.

I have a some pages on my website where I want to use **UpdatePanels**.
On another page of my website, i need to use **ModalPopupExtender** control wich is included in the **AjaxControlToolkit** lib.

The problem that i encountered is that **my UpdatePanels do not work at all if I include the AjaxControlToolkit library in my project** (no need to implement any component of this library, just adding a reference to it in my project). 
If I remove the reference to the lib, it works fine.

Do you have an idea on how to concile those both elements ? UpdatePanel and AjaxControlToolkit lib ?

Thanks a lot for your advice

Here is the simple UpdatePanel code I use:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk" runat="server" Text="show" CommandName="show"></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>


<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="label1"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Repeater1" EventName="ItemCommand" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In code behind, I use this :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Repeater1.DataSource = new List<String>(){"zero", "un", "deux", "trois","quatre"};
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lnk = ((LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lnk"));
        lnk.CommandArgument = e.Item.ItemIndex.ToString();
    }

    protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "show")
            label1.Text = "You click" + e.CommandArgument;
    }
```

Comment: You are definitely getting some javascript errors in your browser. See if you can see any JS errors in your IE and paste them here.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post because i was the same problem when added a reference for AjaxToolKit.dll,
then was looking what could be the problem then found this with the comment to see the javascript errors and was the solution :D

I had in my code a script to get the start of the refresh

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) 
{
   var elementID = sender._activeElement.id;
   ...
}
```

was getting "TypeError: sender._activeElement is undefined"
then changed the

```
var elementID = sender._activeElement.id;
```

to

```
var elementID = sender._postBackSettings.sourceElement.id;
```

and solved my problem.

Without the reference to the dll was working fine and when I remove it.
With the reference I had to change the properties of the element.